how to add double quotation for each items of array in the dataweave
as our postGreSQL server is not Case Sensitive. but there have some tables which are migrated from other DB.  we have to use double quotation for the columns when we select data from db.
for example ,
we got data from API
[{"cloumN1": 1,"cloumN2": 2 }]

i need to transform sql string like
 insert into "tableName" ("cloumN1", "cloumN2") values (1,2)

i used
(payload[0] pluck $$) joinBy ","  

to get string "aA,bB,cC"
i want to know how can i get string '"aA", "bB", cC"' using dataweave?
thanks

Where to you get strings "aA,bB,cC" if the input is [{"cloumN1": 1,"cloumN2": 2 }]?

Also, are the values always numeric? and is it always a single item in the array?

This question is similar to: Mule code to convert elements in array to individual element qoutes.

Did you try
join by "\",\""

such that you can join with "," literally.
You'll need also to add a " at the beginning and at the end

To improve your answer you should make a more complete example and show the result.

I would first map all the keys out of your array of objects, then wrap them in double quotes, then store them in a separate variable. Next, do the same for your values.
Now that you have your keys and values stored separately into arrays, you can map them into Strings, making sure you wrap your keys in double quotes. No need to do that for the values since they can remain as 'Number' types
The following dataweave should accomplish this if you paste this into dataweave playground:


%dw 2.0
output application/java

var postGreData = [{"cloumN1": 1,"cloumN2": 2 }]

var myKeys = postGreData map ((item, index) ->  keysOf(item)) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> (item))

var myValues = postGreData map ((item, index) ->  valuesOf(item)) reduce ((item, accumulator) -> item)

var joinedKeyString =  myKeys map ((item, index) -> ("\"" ++ item ++ "\"")) joinBy ","
var joinedValues = myValues joinBy ","
---
"insert into \"tableName\" (" ++ joinedKeyString as String ++ ") values (" ++ joinedValues as String ++ ")"




You can try below dataweave to acheieve it in a simpler way:
KeysOf Returns an array of keys from key-value pairs within the input object.
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
'"' ++ (keysOf(payload[0]) joinBy  '","') ++ '"'

Attaching the screenshot from dataweave playground:

